# Поиск русских строк cmd\bat

Tags: cmd

В текстовом файле **1.txt** ищу все строки где есть слово "**Документы**" и сохраняю в файл rezultat.txt.

**Использую команду:**

```
FINDSTR /L "Документы" 1.txt > rezultat.txt
```

**Проблема в том что:** слова, написанные на кириллице (на Русском языке), не ищутся. А на английском ищутся. Как решить проблему поиска на русском и решаемая, эта задача, в целом ?

Дополнение, полный код ( Ищу все строки где есть слово Документы и сохраняю результат в файл **rezultat.txt** ):

**Сам Bat файл (код)(Не ищет строки по слову - Документы):**

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /P base="Enter base filename with extension! (eg. MyBase.txt) ->  "
FINDSTR /L "Документы" %base% > rezultat.txt
echo "Rabota zavershena"
pause
```

Comment: Конечно. Если слово искать в той кодировке, в какой оно записано в файле

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, а как правильнее найти подход в данной ситуации. Я так поняла нужно слово переводить в другую кодировку или ?

Comment: Именно так. Программы не ищут буквы. Они ищут байты

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, То есть получается в саму команду нужно вставить FINDSTR /L "Документы" 1.txt > rezultat.txt (и возле слова "Документы" команду перекодировать ? )

Comment: Нет. Декодировать нужно только ту строку, какую ищете

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, А как это сделать на примере ?

Comment: Я понятия не имею, что, где и как вы ищете

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Дополнила вопрос полным кодом, посмотрите если не сложно...